# Freeze panes in a HTML table

Tags: php, css, html-table

I need to freeze the first row for the below table, here's my current code below
Please let me know if you need anymore information

Here's an image of the table: [image]

```
<head>
<style> 
   table,td,th
   {border-collapse:collapse;}
   table.myTable td, table.myTable th { border:1px solid black;padding:5px;
   font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   color:#2C3539;
   font-size:0.80em}

   table
   {width:100%;}
   th{background-color:#B6B6B4;
   height:10px;}
</style>

<table class="myTable">
<?php
//MySQL Database Connect
include 'connect.php';
 echo "
 <tr>
 <th>Name</th>
 <th>Location</th>
 <th>Email</th>
 <th>Mobile</th>
 <th>IMEI</th>
 <th>Phone</th>
 <th>Message</th>
 </tr></Freezing>";

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

   {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['Location'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['Email'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['Mobile'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['IMEI'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['Phone'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['Message'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   }
 echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

Comment: *"I need to freeze the first row for the below table"* – You're going to need to elaborate on that.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NzJKZ.png - this image will show the table, the grey background will be the row I need to freeze, if that makes sense

Comment: I saw the image, I just don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Do you mean making it "fixed" so that it doesn't move?

Comment: Yep, like you can do within Excel. called 'Freeze Panes'

Comment: You can use Matthew's answer below but use `position: fixed;` instead.

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.fixedheadertable.com/ and http://datatables.net/extras/fixedheader/ also Google "fixed header table". You should be able to find a lot of options.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do instead is use the `<thead>` to segment your `<th>` tags. Then you could use either absolute of fixed positioning to have that section float above the others. Here is an example:

**HTML**

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Mobile</th>
        <th>IMEI</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Message</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
...
</tbody>
```

**CSS**

```
thead { 
    display: block;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%
    z-index: 100;
}
```

You may also need to add some padding to the top of the `<tbody>` tag so that the frozen row does not sit over top of any data. Additionally, absolute positioning will be relative to the nearest positioned ancestor, so you may need to add a position to the table as well.

```
table {
    position: relative;
}
tbody {
    padding-top: 1em;
}
```

Comment: I can see where that's going but doesn't do the trick.  http://i.imgur.com/bXdm0O2.png   also it still moves

Comment: Maybe try `display: table-row` instead of display block?

Comment: @Billo Then you need to set your cells to a fixed width size for all.

Comment: Has moved it to the correct position but still moved when scrolling.  Also the width is set on 100% so depending on the screen size the width would change

Comment: Try using `position: fixed` instead of absolute.

Comment: @MatthewR. As per [my original comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639006/freeze-panes-in-a-html-table#comment27442446_18639006)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Good call ;)

Comment: @MatthewR. You did 99% of the work, good call as well ;-) (`+1`)

Answer (score 2):

try this it's using jquery though [Freeze Header](http://brentmuir.com/projects/freezeheader/)